# how does redis/kafka implement forbid duplicate consume

Tags: redis, apache-kafka, message-queue, conflict

While working with redis and other queue, i wonder if it's possible two consumer for the same queue get the same value?

Does anyone know how redis or kafka solve this problem and how's the performance?

Answer (score 0):

I can't say about Redis, but for Kafka it's simple - individual consumers are consume only from specific partition assigned only to it - nobody else works with this partition, and inside this partition it receives messages one by one.

Comment: in my mind, i remember multi client can share the same partition, does it?

Comment: Only if they are in different consumer groups